# How should I write keyboard chord within a sentance, in plain text

Tags: text, standards, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to write out a keyboard shortcut in a sentence, in plain text. This could be in any font - monospaced, or not - but there is no text formatting (color, size, weight), dingbats, or anything like that. For example, if I want the write <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I could write:

- Press Ctrl+Enter to submit the form
- Press Ctrl + Enter to submit the form
- Press CTRL + ENTER to submit the form
- Press [Ctrl] + [Enter] to submit the form
- etc...

Are there any standards for how to write keyboard keys in plain text?

Comment: No standard. Just pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Usually no space around the + because it's a chord, not a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Compare Google vs Apple:

Apple = Command-C | Command-X | Option-Command-Esc
Google =  Ctrl + n | Ctrl + Shift + w | Ctrl + Tab

Google's version makes more sense to me with the + (addition symbol), it's clearly spaced out and not in all caps. Visually more appealing and easier to understand.